# How to test ILOG JRules Ruleset without using DVS?

Tags: unit-testing, ilog, jrules

I'm trying to use JRules BRMS 7.1 for a project. And I found out that DVS has some limitation in testing Ruleset.

It is that it cannot test the content in **collections of complex type** in Excel scenario file templates.

But I understand it is normal as that kind of content is too complex for an Excel table format.

So anyone has any idea what is the best way to test a ruleset that need tons of test cases with lots of complex type input without using DVS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If developers are doing the testing, then use JUnit with an embedded rule engine. If non-technical users need to perform testing, it may be simplest to upgrade to WODM 7.5 which does not have this limitation. If that is not an option, then it is possible to use JRules 7.1 DVS, but it is somewhat complex and involves creating a separate wrapper rule project that takes the output collections as input and in its XOM, performs the comparison with the actual results.

Comment: Hi Raj. Can you please provide docs/links which explains how can we test the rules using JUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Raj Rao is correct, you can use array as expected results (input is easy) but you will have to use hidden JRules API and it is painful anyway.
JUnit or 7.5 is the answer.
Unless you want to pay IBM to do it, even so they may say it is not possible because it is not detailled anywhere :(

Cheers
PS: BTW, arrays of complex types as input is easy for sure and well documented, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your rules as a HTDS service to RES, then you could use SoapUI to test the HTDS web service.

SoapUI allows you to set up test cases that can be used to test different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the rules using Decision Validation Services, you create an Excel scenario file template that you populate with scenarios to test.
Before generating the Excel scenario file template, you must check that your project does not contain any errors or warnings that could prevent the generation of the Excel file.
step1:in your rule explorer select your project in rule project enable the dvs part click check point and make sure that you don't have any errors.
2:create scenario file click next give the name for test project name.xls.
3:pass the values in scenario and expected results in expected results column.
4:you can test multiple scenarios at a time.
5:now close and save the excel file.
6:run configuration right click dvs excel file give any name for test
7:in excel file field click browse and select xls file
8.in rule project field select your rule project
9:in HTML report field select your project and click OK.
10:click apply and run
11:in rule studio right click on your project and click refresh 
12:the HTML file will be generated in project.
13:right click and open with web browser and observe the result of your scenarios.
14:you have successfully enabled dvs